# Faster way to filter group values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with as many as `90,000` rows. I need to filter the dataframes for identical INDEX column values and send it over to a function which iterates the filtered dataframes. I was wondering if there is a quicker way to filter the dataframes other than using `groupby`.

This is what I have. Is there any way to speed this up? 
`arr` variable is an list of integers from `10000 to 90000.`

```
group1 = df1.groupby(["INDEX"], sort=False)
group2 = df2.groupby(["INDEX"], sort=False)


# Iterates through list arr and calls func repetitively
for names in map(str.upper, arr):
    # print(names)
    try:
        func(group1.get_group(names), group2.get_group(names))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What is it you need to do once you've filtered them/what does `func` do? It's probably the iteration that's slowing you down, rather than `groupby`, and avoiding that is where you'd likely see the biggest gains.

Comment: No it's not the function that makes it slow. I timed it with and without calling the function and there's only 3 seconds difference. `groupby` is taking all the time.

Comment: What kind of slowdown are you seeing, and were you still iterating through and calling `.get_groups`? It's helpful to know what you're doing next even when just trying to eliminate the `groupby`. It helps in figuring out whether any column operations could skip it and do what you want, or the mechanics of how you'd go about using `.apply` or `.iterrows`.